# INNER JOIN with GROUP BY in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, inner-join, pymongo, lookup

I am trying to do an INNER JOIN with a GROUP BY in MongoDB. I am not getting any errors but no results either.

TableOne:

---

|**Site**|**Starts**|**date**  |

---

| Google| 900       |2019-10-13|

| FB    | 300       |2019-10-10|

| Yahoo | 100       |2019-10-11|

---

TableTWO:

---

|**Finishes**  |**date** |

---

| 5          |2019-10-13|

| 4          |2019-10-10|

| 3          |2019-10-11|

Desired Output:

---

### |**Site**|**Starts**|**date**  | Finishes |

| Google| 900       |2019-10-13|   5      |

| FB    | 300       |2019-10-10|   4      |

| Yahoo | 100       |2019-10-11|   3      |

---

SQL:

```
SELECT a.site, r.date, SUM(a.starts), SUM(r.finishes) FROM tableONE a INNER JOIN tableTWO r 
ON a.site = r.site
GROUP BY a.site, r.date
ORDER BY 1
```

My MongoDB query:

```
db.tableONEaggregate([
        {
            '$match': { 'date': {
                        '$gte': '2019-09-19',
                        '$lte': '2019-10-19'
        } }
        }, 
        { '$lookup': {
                'localField': 'site',
                'from': 'tableTWO',
                'foreignField': 'site',
                'as': 'site_yo'
        } },
            { '$unwind': '$site_yo' },
         {
            '$group': {
                '_id': {
                    'site': '$site',
                    'date': '$site_yo.date',
                },
                'starts': {
                    '$sum': '$starts'
                },
                'finishes': {
                    '$sum': '$finishes'
                }
            }
        }, {
            '$project': {
                '_id': 0,
                'site': '$_id.site',
                'date': '$_id.date',
                'starts': '$starts',
                'finishes': '$starts'
            }
        }, {
            '$sort': {
                'starts': -1
            }
        }, {
            '$limit': 100
        }
    ])
```

I am not getting any results. What us wrong with my Mongo Query?

Comment: Could you add some sample data from tableONE and tableTWO and a desired output? The query seems to give me output with trivial data added to the two tables, so it's hard to even guess why you're not getting anything.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I have added them. Its just a simple Inner JOin and grouping values from both tables because of the sum

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using a false foreign key within your Join. If you wanna join two tables you have to use ON primarykeyOfTable1 = ForeignkeyOfTable2
In your case this would be

SELECT a.site, r.date, SUM(a.starts), SUM(r.finishes) FROM tableONE a INNER JOIN tableTWO r 
ON a.date = r.date
GROUP BY a.site, r.date
ORDER BY 1